# Can this chained comparison really be simplified like PyCharm claims?

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison, pycharm

I have a class with two integer attributes, `_xp` and `level`. I have a `while` loop which compares these two to make sure they're both positive:

```
while self.level > 0 and self._xp < 0:
    self.level -= 1
    self._xp += self.get_xp_quota()
```

My PyCharm claims this can be simplified:

[image: Simplify chained comparison]

Can it really? I want to make sure before reporting a bug to PyCharm.

I also found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502775/pycharm-simplify-chained-comparison) but in that case the two variables were the same, mine has two different attributes.

Comment: Your *value* is the same. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh darn, silly me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIRC, you could rewrite this as:

```
while self._xp < 0 < self.level:
    self.level -= 1
    self._xp += self.get_xp_quota()
```

as per your reference above. It doesn't really matter that there's 2 different attributes or the same variable, ultimately you are simply comparing the values of each.

Let me know if that works.