# Writing the right inequality in python?

Tags: python, inequality

Would python intrepet this:

```
if hour < 7 and hour > 0 or hour > 20 and hour < 23:
```

the same as

```
if  7 > hour > 0 or 23 > hour > 20 (this one is just the usual mathematical inequality)
```

if not then what should I write to tell python this inequality?

Comment: You can use `if (0<hour<7 or 20<hour<23):`

Comment: Did you try to check if they are the same? what's the purpose of the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplify Chained Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502775/simplify-chained-comparison)

Comment: Quoting the Zen of Python: "Readability counts.". I would just use parenthesis.

Comment: according to [operator pecedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), AND is stronger so it's the same, it's just harder to read

Comment: Why *don't* you use the second version? If you think the versions are different, *which one* do you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [comparison chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0535/).

```
if (0 < hour < 7) or (20 < hour < 23):
    # do stuff
```

(Parenthesis for emphasis.)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use parentheses to be sure:

```
if (hour < 7 and hour > 0) or (hour > 20 and hour < 23):
```