# Why does <= evaluate a range of characters for a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have an assignment to write a python program that asks the user to input a single character and then checks if it is an alphabetical digit (not special characters) or a digit or neither with neither and prints what it is.

I was testing the method below out of curiosity thinking it will return an error or print Invalid input. But lo and behold it actually works perfectly but I have no idea why.

```
c = input("Enter a character: ")

if 'a' <= c.lower() <= 'z' and len(c) == 1:   # .lower() in case the input is either capital or lowercase
    print('Your character', "'" + c + "'", 'is an alphabetical letter')
elif '0' <= c <= '9' and len(c) == 1:
    print('Your character', "'" + c + "'", 'is a digit')
else:
    print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: It works because the character you put in is between 'a' and 'z' and then probably between 0 and 9, it works, can you specify what you don't understand?

Comment: You're seeing chained comparison (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502847/51685) and the fact that strings are comparable to each other.

Comment: Here's the answer why strings are compared and how https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [value comparison docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> Strings (instances of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)) compare lexicographically using the numerical Unicode code points (the result of the built-in function [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)) of their characters.

Answer (score 0):

It compares the ASCII value of your character with the ASCII value of 'a' & 'z', same thing about digits since they are in the form of characters.

Comment: "ASCII" isn't correct, you can also compare non-ASCII characters just fine.