# Simplify Chained Comparison for line with two variables

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

In my [read_lines function](https://github.com/SurpriseDog/readlines/blob/main/readlines.py), pylint is giving the error:

```
R1716: Simplify chained comparison between the operands (chained-comparison)
```

but unlike the question I found here: [Simplify Chained Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26502775/simplify-chained-comparison), my line involves two variables, not one and I'm not really sure how I can simplify it any further:

```
elif start < 0 and 0 < end < inf:
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's suggesting you replace `a < b and b < c` with `a < b < c`. Here, `b` is `0`.

Comment: `start < 0 < end < inf` is what pylint is expecting I assume, though it is debatable whether that actually helps readability. Personally, I would just add a pylint ignore comment, as I don't really think it helps.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks, didn't think of that. Seems like a case of "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should," lol.